# Dask DF operation takes a long time after 100% progress in Dask dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I am working with a large CSV (~60GB; ~250M rows) with Dask in Jupyter.

The first thing I want to do with the DF after loading it is to concatenate two string columns. I can do so successfully, but I noticed that cell execution time does not seem to decrease with higher workers counts (I tried 5, 10, and 20 on a machine with 64 logical cores). If anything, every five or so workers seem to add an extra minute to execution time.

Meanwhile, the progress bar of Dask's dashboard suggests that the task scales well with worker count. At 5 workers the task finishes (ac. to the dashboard) in about 10-15 min. At 20 workers the stream visualisation suggests task completion in roughly 3-5 min. But cell execution time remains around 25 min, i.e. in the 5-worker case the cell will appear to be hanging for an extra 10-15 min. after the stream has finished; in the 20-worker case -- for 20-22 more min., with no evidence of worker activity as far as I can see.

This is the code that I'm running:

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=20)
client = Client(cluster)

df = dd.read_csv('df_name.csv', dtype={'col1': 'object', 'col2': 'object'})

with ProgressBar():
    df["col_merged"] = df["col3"]+df["col4"]
    df = df.compute()
```

Python version: 3.9.1
Dask version: 2021.06.2

What am I missing? Could this simply be overhead from having Dask to coordinate several workers?

Comment: Oh, also, no progress bar is displayed in Jupyter for whatever reason. I will check if running the same code without `ProgressBar()` will take any less time and edit the post/comment after I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @SultanOrazbayev 's answer, the specific thing that's taking time after the tasks have all been done, is copying data from the workers into your client process to assemble the single in-memory dataframe that you have asked for. This is not a "task", as all the computing has already happened, and does not parallelise well, because the client is a single thread pulling data from the workers.

As with the comment above: if you want to achieve parallelism, you need to load the data in workers (which dd.read_csv does) and act on them in workers o get your result. You should on `.compute()` relatively small things. Conversely, if your data first comfortably into memory, there was probably nothing to be gained by having dask involved at all, just use pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Running

```py
df = df.compute()
```

will attempt to load all the 250M rows into memory. If this is feasible with your machine, you will still spend a lot of time because each worker is going to send their chunk, so there will be a lot of data transfer...

The core idea is to bring into memory only the results of the reduced calculations, and distribute the workload among the workers until then.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks!

I accepted @mdurant's answer as, in addition to pointing out the problem, they outlined an easy fix (giving each worker a CSV chunk of their own). Hope that's okay.